# Complex pivot/unpivot operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I'm new to pivot / unpivot & its syntax and I find it difficult to wrap my head around it. My problem is pretty complex, at least it is to me.

The case: I have test data from different processors, with a test value for a time range of let's say 200 seconds.

My data is currently structured like this:

```
TestName   |   Brand  |  Line   |  Model   | Time   |  Value  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
IntelTest1 |   Intel  |   i7    |   8700k  |  1     |   0.20  |
IntelTest1 |   Intel  |   i7    |   8700k  |  2     |   0.35  |
IntelTest1 |   Intel  |   i7    |   8700k  |  3     |   0.89  |
IntelTest1 |   ...    |  ...    |   ...    |  ...   |   ...   |
AmdTest1   |   AMD    | Ryzen 5 |   1600   |  1     |   0.12  |
AmdTest1   |   AMD    | Ryzen 5 |   1600   |  2     |   0.34  |
AmdTest1   |   AMD    | Ryzen 5 |   1600   |  3     |   0.51  |
AmdTest1   |   ...    |  ...    |   ...    |  ...   |   ...   |
...        |   ...    |  ...    |   ...    |  ...   |   ...   |
```

I need to get it into the following format for reporting purposes:

```
RowNumber   |  Time  |  IntelTest1 |   AmdTest1  | ...
--------------------------------------------------
1           |        |  IntelTest1 |   AmdTest1  |  
2           |        |    Intel    |     AMD     | 
3           |        |     i7      |   Ryzen 5   | 
4           |        |    8700k    |    1600     |
5           |   1    |    0.20     |    0.12     |
6           |   2    |    0.35     |    0.34     |
7           |   3    |    0.89     |    0.51     |
8           |   4    |    ...      |    ...      |
```

In short, I need the metadata (TestName, Brand, Line and Model) for each Test first, followed by the values for each point in time. The columns should be each testname.

I've been trying with pivoting (dynamically since the number of 'names' is variable) and unpivoting but I can't figure out how to structure it correctly.

Do I need multiple operations to accomplish this?

Edit: made the example a little clearer (hopefully).

Comment: I can't actually see how to derive that transformation. I can see you've tried to explain but i'm afraid, at least to me, it doesn't do enough. Can you edit your post and try to explain the transformation in more detail please? Can a time have more than 2 values as well? If so, what happens? You imply in your sample data you have more columns after `abf`. if you do, what are they?

Comment: Far better dealt with in a presentation tool (application or report builder) rather than trying to do this in the database. You're mixing values of multiple different data types in a single column which isn't really the way we work with SQL (in the alternative, we have to throw away data types and just work with strings - which is why this points to being a presentation concern rather than a data one)

Comment: Agreed with @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think i understood the logic, in the end, however, the fact that the OP implies that they can have more columns after `abf` concerns me. Expecially as i have no idea what needs to therefore going into the subsquent rows for the the "header" values. Clearly `Shop` and `Model` are going in the first columns (`abc` and `abf`) but if there's a column `abh` what goes in the column when `abf` has a value of `'Z'` and `'D'`. there's no further split.

Comment: Edited the example. Does this make more sense?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the presentation tool isn't flexible enough to obtain the wanted result, which is why I want to create a view to import it in the tool directly. Working with string data is not necessarily a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

you should not be doing in SQL. But if you really have to then try something like below query

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/DMRZO39612)**</kbd>

```
create table sample (TestName varchar(100),Brand varchar(100), Line varchar(100), Model varchar(100), Time int, Value decimal(5,2))
insert into sample values
('IntelTest1','Intel','i7', '8700k',1, 0.20)
,('IntelTest1','Intel','i7', '8700k',2, 0.35)
,('IntelTest1','Intel','i7', '8700k',3, 0.89)
,('AmdTest1','AMD','Ryzen 5', '1600',1, 0.12)
,('AmdTest1','AMD','Ryzen 5', '1600',2, 0.34);

select
rownumber= row_number() over ( order by (select 1)), * 
from
(
select [Time]=Null ,[IntelTest1]=[1],
[Amdtest1]=[2]
from
(
    select 
     rownum=row_number() over(order by (select 1) ) , * 
    from
    (
      select 
         distinct 
         TestName, 
         Brand,
         Line,
         Model
      from sample
    )s
)s
unpivot
( data for keys in (TestName, Brand, Line, Model))up
pivot
( max(data) for rownum in ([1],[2]))p
union all
select Time,[IntelTest1]=Cast([IntelTest1] as varchar(max)),[AMDTest1]=cast([AMDTest1] as varchar(max)) from
(select  TestName,Time, Value  from sample)s
pivot
(max(value) for TestName in ([IntelTest1],[AMDTest1]))p
)t
```

Comment: Bear in mind though that the OP stated "dynamically since the number of 'names' is variable" - so you need to accommodate a variable set of columns rather than just `IntelTest1` and `AMDTest1` - which makes for some very messy dynamic SQL to *generate* something like your sample.